# save geojson as shapefile in R

Tags: r, geojson, terra

I read the file from this link in R (Microsoft Office building footprint)

https://minedbuildings.blob.core.windows.net/global-buildings/2023-06-27/global-buildings.geojsonl/RegionName%3DNetherlands/quadkey%3D120200313/part-00138-7b73ad6b-e7c8-4e22-9fa2-01d140ca911d.c000.csv.gz

After unzipping the file, I get a csv which I convert into geojson. How do I save it as a shapefile either using sf or terra

```
library(R.utils)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(geojson)


file_name <- "part-00138-7b73ad6b-e7c8-4e22-9fa2-01d140ca911d.c000.csv.gz"
R.utils::gunzip(file_name))

readLines(file_name) %>% 
 paste(collapse = ", ") %>%
 {paste0('{"type": "FeatureCollection",
         "features": [', ., "]}")} -> j

x <- to_geojson(j)
class(x)

"geofeaturecollection" "geojson"

sf::st_write(x, dsn = getwd(), "temp.shp")
Error in UseMethod("st_write") : 
 no applicable method for 'st_write' applied to an object of class "c('geofeaturecollection', 'geojson')"

terra::writeVector(x, 'temp.shp')
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeVector’ for signature ‘"geofeaturecollection", "character"’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument for [`sf::st_read()`](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/st_read.html) is `dsn` (data source name). The docs state:

> interpretation varies by driver - for some drivers `dsn` is a file name, but may also be a folder, or contain the name and access credentials of a database); in case of GeoJSON, `dsn` may be the character string holding the geojson data.

So you can just provide your character string. Here's a simpler, complete example with no unzipping:

```r
# Read some sample geojson data
x <- readLines("https://dataworks.calderdale.gov.uk/download/24mx6/94l/VenuesNov2022.geojson")

dat <- sf::st_read(x)
#   using driver `GeoJSON'
# Simple feature collection with 13 features and 9 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -2.098113 ymin: 53.70398 xmax: -1.786043 ymax: 53.74124
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84

sf::st_write(dat, "tmp.shp", append = FALSE)
```

Or in your case:

```r
dat  <- sf::st_read(j)
sf::st_write(dat, "tmp.shp", append = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With "terra" that would be

```
library(terra)
f <- "https://dataworks.calderdale.gov.uk/download/24mx6/94l/VenuesNov2022.geojson"

v <- vect(f)
writeVector(v, "test.json")
```